# Decompress streaming BZ2 from memory in Python

Tags: python, compression, bzip2

I have a block of CSV data bz2 compressed data in memory

```
compressed = load_from_network_service(...)
```

I would like to iterate over a stream of decompressed lines.

```
for line in bz2_decompress_stream(compressed):
    ...
```

Does such a function exist?

In principle I could write to disk then read in using `bz2.BZ2File`, which only seems to want to consume a filename

```
with open('tmp', 'w') as f: 
    f.write(compressed)
with bz2.BZ2File('tmp') as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

But, for my current application disk I/O is a premium, so this is a pain.

Presumably the `bz2.BZ2Decompressor` object might be helpful here.  My experience with it is that I give it my compressed data and it gives me the entire decompressed result; it doesn't seem to stream.  Perhaps this is a limitation of my data?

Comment: "filename" is just misleading, you can also give it a file object. From the doc: "If filename is a str or bytes object, open the named file directly. Otherwise, filename should be a file object, which will be used to read or write the compressed data."

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct problems:

1. streaming
2. not writing to disk

In order to solve 2., you are right that you can use `bz2.BZ2Compressor`. But a solution to 1.... entirely depends on what exactly your first line

`compressed = load_from_network_service(...)`

really returns. If `compressed` is a string, then there is not much you can do: you have to wait until you have retrieved it all, and then decompress. Instead, if for instance it is an incrementally "filled" `StringIO`, then you can do something like (untested):

```
decompressed = ''
while True:
    compressed_chunk = compressed.read(100)
    # Can be empty (even before the stream is exhausted):
    decompressed_chunk = decompressor.decompress(data)
    if decompressed_chunk:
        decompressed += decompressed_chunk
        new_lines = decompressed.splitlines()
        decompressed = new_lines[-1]
        for line in new_lines[:-1]:
            do_something(line)
    if len(chunk) < 100:
        # Reached EOF
        break
```

Comment: I receive a full compressed string back.  I want to stream the decompression process which is still valuable even with the full original input in memory.  It sounds like I should manually stream data to the decompressor and that it will handle holding on to chunks of tails of data for me.

Comment: Yes, then a ``compressed = StringIO(compressed)`` before my solution may suffice.